# Tab validation in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Im using MVC3 application with jquery validation. I have disabled hidden field validation in jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js using this ignore: ":hidden".

I have two tabs in my application. When I click submit, only the tab that is highlighted gets validated even though I have another tab, the fields are not getting validated there on another tab. So I decided to use a javascript function which would get all the input fields on my tabs and validate them.

```
function NextOnclick() {
     for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            $('input', '#tab' + i).valid();

        }
}
```

However when the validate method is called it gives me the error

```
Form is null or not an object
```

What am i doing wrong here? Is there any other approach to do tab validation in MVC3, other than eager validation? I want to do validation on form submit. Thanks!

Comment: jquery validate works for inputs inside a form element. Either wrap all the tabs inside a form, either add a form inside each tab

Comment: all the tabs are inside a form element but still im getting the same error.

Comment: Hidden field validation is disabled by default for the last several versions of this plugin.  So there is no need to use the `ignore` rule at all.